# How to create a new data frame based on standard deviation for multiple variables in R

Tags: r

I'd like to create a new data frame "data.frame.final" from an existing one based on a condition - for example, +/-3 standard deviations for all variables that I have in my data frame.

I have 5 variables and I need to generate a new data frame with the same criteria, +/- 3 SD, applied to all.

```
tt <- "id_animal farm protein fat casein lactose
1  AG   3.0  9.0  2.3 1.5
2  AG   3.0  9.7  3.3 1.3
3  FA   2.0  7.6  4.3 2.4
4  AB   1.5  6.9  5.4 2.8
5  AB   2.9  7.3  3.4 2.9"

dataframe1 <- read.table (text=tt, header=T)
```

In `data.frame.final` I want only values that are within +/- 3 SD for each variable. For values that are lower or higher than 3 SD, I'd like to insert "NA".

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: I doubt there is a single value in your example outside +/- 3 SDs. You should check out `?scale` however. E.g. `scale(dataframe1[c("protein","fat","casein","lactose")])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no values in your example data more than 3 standard deviations from the mean. Here's a modified example

```
tx <- "id_animal farm protein fat casein lactose
1  AG   3.0  9.0  2.3 1.5
2  AG   3.0  910.7  3.3 1.3
3  FA   2.0  7.6  4.3 25.4
4  AB   1.5  6.9  555.4 2.8
5  AB   220.9  7.3  3.4 2.9"

df <- read.table (text=tx, header=T)

df

#   id_animal farm protein   fat casein lactose
# 1         1   AG     3.0   9.0    2.3     1.5
# 2         2   AG     3.0 910.7    3.3     1.3
# 3         3   FA     2.0   7.6    4.3    25.4
# 4         4   AB     1.5   6.9  555.4     2.8
# 5         5   AB   220.9   7.3    3.4     2.9
```

Actually, there are still no values more than 3 standard deviations from the mean. I'll use 1 standard deviation instead. Change `n_sds` to control this.

For all columns but the first two, `replace` all values not(`!`) `between` the two values give by `mean(.) + c(-1, 1)*n_sds*sd(.)`, i.e. the mean minus `n_sds*sd(.)` and the mean plus `n_sds*sd(.)`, with `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

n_sds <- 1

df %>% 
  mutate_at(-(1:2), ~ {
    rng <- mean(.) + c(-1, 1)*n_sds*sd(.)
    replace(., !between(., rng[1], rng[2]), NA)
  })
#   id_animal farm protein fat casein lactose
# 1         1   AG     3.0 9.0    2.3     1.5
# 2         2   AG     3.0  NA    3.3     1.3
# 3         3   FA     2.0 7.6    4.3      NA
# 4         4   AB     1.5 6.9     NA     2.8
# 5         5   AB      NA 7.3    3.4     2.9
```

Comment: Thank you so much! works perfectly! @IceCreamToucan